# Redirect site using session script

Tags: php, session, redirect

I´m trying to redirect visitor when visits the page for first time to site 1. The second visit the script will redirect the visitor to site 2.  I want to use session. But it doesn´t work right and I dont know where is the mistake.

Logic should be: If you are here for the first time you will be redirected to site 1, if you are here for the second time you will be redirected to side 2.

this is the code i made:

```
session_start();

if ($_SESSION["header"] = " " || !isset($_SESSION)) 
{
    $_SESSION["header"] = "1"; 
    echo header("Location: http://site 1");

    }
else
{
  session_destroy();
    echo header("Location: http://site 2");
    exit();
}
```

well I´m not sure if the session is the right way how to do it

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible and not recommended to do it with a session. Because after a while the session gets destroyed automatically.
I rather you to use cookies. 
The code is similar to your code. The only difference between sessions and cookies is that cookies can be setted for lifetime

Answer (score 0):

You're using this code which is wrong.

```
$_SESSION["header"] = " "
```

`$_SESSION["header"] = " "` means to assign ' ' to `$_SESSION["header"]`

---

It should be:

```
$_SESSION["header"] == " "
```

`$_SESSION["header"] == " "` means `$_SESSION["header"]` is equal to ' '

---

`==` is for **comparison**, `=` is for **assignment**, and `===` is for **identical** or **same type**.

More information at http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php.